# Что мешает работать autocomplete?

Tags: html, input, autocomplete

Всем привет, будьте добры подскажите в чем может быть причина.
Не работает autocomplete у input на приходящие смс.

Перепробовал разное:

1. Просто ставил autocomplete=on
2. autocomplete="one-time-code" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]" type="text"
3. у form ставил и убирал autocomplete так же

Или сейчас эта функция в браузерах(либо на андроид-устройствах) отключена? Если так, можете дать статью об этом?

Comment: Ну, насколько я понимаю [документацию](https://developer.chrome.com/articles/web-otp/), нужно ещё в javascript-коде настроить использование OTP

Comment: А если без javascript-кода, то, насколько я понимаю ту же документацию, атрибут autocomplete="one-time-code" просто включает подсказку в клавиатуре, и только на айфонах